# File of packages in overleaf

Tags: packages, overleaf, multiple-files

I was wondering if there is a way in overleaf, to create a sort of file in wich you put all the packages you're going to use in your project, and then you would just "import" it in your main and doing so would implement all the packages you're going to use; and if that is posible what would be the type of that file, would it be a class or a package itself?
Thank you so much.

Comment: just have a `mypackages.sty` with a list of `\usepackage{something}\usepackage{...}...` and put `\usepackage{mypackages}` in your main document

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did this but it still is not working, could you link an example please? Or when you say maek a list are you reffering to a list with this format \begin{itemize}... Because I just put them there like \usepackage{something}\usepackage{...}.

Comment: if you add a file to your overleaf project that just has `\usepackage{array,longtable,tikz,enumitem}`  and load that file in to your document with `\usepackage{mypackages}` then it will work